# Karel The Robot - rightIsBlocked() is undefined for the type

Tags: java, karel

I am a AP Comp Sci student and we have been given an assignment to code karel the robot to climb over a few hurdles
I put the code:

```
private void ascendHurdle(){
        r.turnLeft();
        while (rightIsBlocked()) {
            r.move();
        }
        r.turnRight();  
    }
```

it says that rightIsBlocked is undefined for the type however on the documentation it says that it is a valid command
[https://www.cs.mtsu.edu/~untch/karel/selection.html](https://www.cs.mtsu.edu/%7Euntch/karel/selection.html) <--- the documentation I used
Please help

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume that `r` is the object that represents your robot. Although it's not very clear based on the documentation, `rightIsBlocked()` is probably not static, so you'd have to use `r.rightIsBlocked()` (because `r` is your instance of the robot's class).

I could be wrong, but hopefully this helps.

Comment: yes r is my robot's name and I did try adding r. however it did not work